# Virtual Key slant movement

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, key, virtual-keyboard

```
public void Move(VirtualKey direction, double boardX, double boardY)
{
    switch (direction)
    {
        case VirtualKey.Up:
            if (Y - _StepSize >= 0)
                this.Y -= this._StepSize;
            break;
        case VirtualKey.Down:
            if (Y + _StepSize <= boardY)
                this.Y += this._StepSize;
            break;
        case VirtualKey.Right:
            if (X + _StepSize <= boardX)
                this.X += this._StepSize;
            break;
        case VirtualKey.Left:
            if(X - _StepSize >= 0)
            this.X -= this._StepSize;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

I want to use 2 keys to move in slant. How do I use up and right together or down and left together for example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CoreWindow.GetKeyState` to test all currently pressed key combinations.

The following example tests if the arrow up key and arrow right key are simultaneously pressed:

```
partial class MainPage : Page
{
  protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    CoreWindow currentCoreWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
    if (currentCoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Up).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
      && currentCoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Right).HasFlag(CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down))
    {
      // Handle UP + Right keys pressed
    }
  }
}
```